# C# WPF - Popup which doesn't get focused

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, focus

Im simply trying to make a little popup which shows a message in the corner. This Popup shuld be at the top of every other Window which I achieved with "TopMost", but I can't seem to get the unfocusable thing to work...

**My PopUp XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="message.Popup"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:message"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Popup" Height="129.808" Width="300" Focusable="False" Topmost="True">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="179*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="113*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="272" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

</Grid>
```

**How I call it (from annother Window):**

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
      new Popup(textBox.Text).Show();
}
```

**PopUp code:**

```
public Popup(string text)
{
      InitializeComponent();

      label.Content = text;
}
```

Comment: code please....

Comment: Without seeing the code or XAML that you have written so far, no one can provide good advice on what you have missed or on something different to try.  Without some posted code or a very detailed explanation of what you have tried that didn't work, this question will most likely be closed soon.

Comment: Alright I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must define your Mainwindow as Owner of the Popup and center the StartupLocation Property. Something like this:

```
            PopUpWindow.Owner = MainWindow;
            PopUpWindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
```

Or if you are calling it from another window:

```
            PopUpWindow.Owner = this;
            PopUpWindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
```

However I must say: this is not MVVM, since you are storing text in the Window class, and I strongly recommend you start reading about MVVM.

Comment: this is the right answer. please mark it as such ;)